# O quão isolado deve ser o core de uma aplicação feita em arquitetura limpa, e até onde vai esse isolamento?

Tags: java, arquitetura-de-software

Então, estou estudando a Clean Architecture e acabei tendo as seguintes dúvidas:

1. Se no core da aplicação eu terei as minhas representações de entidades ex: Pessoa(id, nome) para a manipulação nos casos de uso e validações de regras de negócio, e no dataprovider(ou gateway) terei o PessoaEntity(id, nome, createDate, updateDate, ...) que é referente ao banco. Onde entra os Dto's que serão enviados ao entrypoint e seus mappers?
2. Se o objetivo do da arquitetura limpa é a de ser independente, não podendo haver no core da aplicação uma referência externa a ele, utilizar as especificações da linguagem por exemplo as do java: jakarta (@Inject, @Named) ou jakarta.validations (@NotNull @NotEmpty)  iria quebrar esse princípio mesmo sendo especificações da própria linguagem?
3. Até onde vai o isolamento do core? se o core se isola apenas de frameworks e permite bibliotecas como (lombok, mapstruct, especificações, ...) ou se isola de absolutamente tudo.

Answer (score -2):

1- Dto's e mappers:
Os Dto's (Data Transfer Objects) e seus respectivos mappers devem ser implementados na camada de Application, que fica acima da camada de Core e abaixo da camada de Infrastructure. O papel da camada de Application é orquestrar os casos de uso da aplicação, utilizando as entidades do Core e as implementações dos gateways do Infrastructure. Portanto, é nessa camada que ocorre a comunicação com as camadas externas à aplicação, como a camada de Presentation (entrypoints). Para isso, são utilizados os Dto's, que são objetos utilizados para transferir dados entre as camadas. Os mappers são responsáveis por converter as entidades do Core em Dto's e vice-versa.

2-Especificações da linguagem:
Utilizar as especificações da linguagem não necessariamente quebra o princípio da independência do Core. É possível utilizar as anotações da linguagem, como @Inject e @NotNull, sem criar acoplamento com as camadas externas. Isso pode ser feito através de frameworks que permitem a injeção de dependências e a validação de dados de forma independente, sem que o Core tenha que conhecer os detalhes da implementação. Um exemplo disso é o Spring Framework para Java.

3-Isolamento do Core:
O isolamento do Core deve ser o máximo possível, mas é importante lembrar que ele não deve ser uma caixa preta isolada do restante da aplicação. Algumas bibliotecas, como as que você mencionou (Lombok, Mapstruct), podem ser utilizadas sem quebrar o isolamento do Core. No entanto, é importante ter cuidado para não utilizar bibliotecas que possam criar acoplamento entre as camadas ou que dependam diretamente de frameworks externos. O ideal é que o Core dependa apenas de bibliotecas que permitam a implementação de regras de negócio e que possam ser facilmente substituídas, caso necessário.

Answer (score -2):

1. Veja bem, o "core" do seu projeto deve conter a representação dos seus modelos e regras de negócio apenas se você quer tornar o seu código portável para outras aplicações, de forma bem simplista, se você copiar o seu pacote "core" do projeto A para o projeto B, o projeto B deve continuar funcionando com a menor quantidade de alterações e dependência possível. Observe que o projeto B pode usar um banco de dados diferente do projeto A, uma saída de dados diferente (no projeto A: JSON, no projeto B: xml, por exemplo). Recomendo dar uma olhada em arquitetura hexagonal.
2. Sobre o uso de especificações da linguagem: Não necessariamente quebra a independência, uma vez que elas foram criadas justamente para permitir o baixo acoplamento, por exemplo a especificação JPA, em um projeto qualquer eu posso usar o Hibernate e em um outro projeto posso utilizar o Spring Data JPA, simplesmente mudando essa ou aquela biblioteca(teoricamente).
3. Sobre o isolamento do core: Ele deve ser o máximo possível, porém ser autosuficiente em manter suas regras de negócios. Exemplo: O core deve saber como manipular os dados de suas representações, mas não precisa como esses dados devem ser persistidos(via api, via banco, via arquivo de texto e etc)

> Recomendo fortemente o estudo da arquitetura hexagonal, ela leva ao
> extremo esse conceito do core, e vai permitir você ter uma perspectiva
> mais clara.